# XHR get response javascript not being executed

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

Sorry if its duplicate. I could not find exact answer.

I am using Xhr and the response has javascript. I am expecting the javascript in the xhr response to be executed. It works in IE 7 but does not work in any other browser. Do you know what is happening?

Source code:

```
//Displays the Rule Grid via 'send to' button on bulletins upload page
```

Javascript file:

```
showRules: function() 
{
    showLoader();
    var contentPane = new dojox.layout.ContentPane(
    { 
        executescripts: true, 
        scriptseparation: false, 
        preventCache: true
    });
    
    dojo.xhrGet({
        url: "/RuleManagement/ShowRuleGrid?type=default",
        sync: true,
        handleAs: "text",
        preventCache: true,
        load: dojo.hitch(this, function(data)
        {
            contentPane.setContent(data);
        }),
        error: dojo.hitch(this, function (error, args) {
            console.error("error: " + error.description);
            console.log("args: " + args.query);
        })
    });
    fs.core.CreateAndShowDialogDynamic(null, contentPane.domNode.innerHTML, null, true, 750);
    
    hideLoader();        
}
```

My ascx file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gridHelper = null;
alert('RuleGridHelper callback!');
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    gridHelper = new RuleGridHelper(
        dojo.byId("<%= idRuleGridContainer %>"),
        [
            "<%= Interpreter.Action.Replace("\"", "\\\"") %>", 
            "<%= Interpreter.RuleName.Replace("\"", "\\\"") %>", 
            "<%= Interpreter.ColumnHeaderBrandTitle.Replace("\"", "\\\"") %>", 
            "<%= Interpreter.IACreatedBy.Replace("\"", "\\\"") %>", 
            "<%= Interpreter.DateCreated.Replace("\"", "\\\"") %>",
            "<%= Interpreter.DateModified.Replace("\"", "\\\"") %>"
        ],
        "<%= ViewData.Model.SearchResultsJson.Replace("\"", "\\\"") %>",
        true,
        "<%= ViewData.Model.RuleSelectedCallbackJS.Replace("\"", "\\\"") %>",
        true,
        <%= ViewData.Model.IsViewMode.ToString().ToLower() %>
    ); 
    
    dojo.connect
    (
        dojo.byId("<%= idCreateNewButton %>"), 
        "onclick", 
        function(evt) { fs.core.SynchronousContentPaneDialog("<%= Url.Action(MVC.InternalAdmin.RuleManagement.ShowCreateNewRule(ViewData.Model.RuleType)) %>", 770, 650, true); }
    );
});
```

The javascript from the xhr get response is not being executed in chrome and other browser.

Comment: try adding the source code here

Comment: I have updated post with code @SubhashisPandey